# How to add web service ability in existing RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services

I wrote a web application in ROR, but I want it supports web service, so that I can do the same things on non-web application platform. What should I do to add web service ability to my web application... ...or I need to reinvent my application, to write a separate web service independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to use responds_to in your controllers. [Here](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/3/27/web-services-rails-style) is a good explanation.

Comment: looks easy, can I return JSON instead of XML?

Comment: yes, read this for more details. http://www.neeraj.name/blog/articles/612-rails-under-the-hood-how-respond_to-works